# XMLHttpRequest to Restivus API

Tags: javascript, meteor, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

I have got a problem when sending a cross domain XMLHttpRequest to a Restivus API.
Here my code for the client side script:

```
var xhrurl = 'http://example.com:3000/api/test';
var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', xhrurl);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-User-Id",object.apiUser);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token",object.apiKey);
xhr.send();
```

Here the function createCORSRequest

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}
```

When sending it to my API the response is 401 unauthorized. The apiKey and UserId are correct because I have tested them with Postman so there should not be the problem.

My backend is Meteor using Restivus for the API.

I have added these lines on the top of the server side script to ensure that everything is accepted.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-User-Id, X-Auth-Token");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-MaxAge", "3628800");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
return next();
});
```

Furthermore I have defined the routes for the restivus call like the following:

```
Restivus.addRoute('test/', {authRequired: true}, {
post: {
  action: function () {
    var test=Projects.find({userId:this.userId, _id: this.bodyParams.project}).count();
    if(this.bodyParams.msg==""||this.bodyParams.msg==undefined||this.bodyParams.project==""||this.bodyParams.project==undefined||test!=1){
      return 'Something went wrong'
    }
    var test = Test.insert({msg: this.bodyParams.msg, date: new Date(), userId : this.userId, fixed: false, project: this.bodyParams.project});
    if (test) {
      return {statusCode:200,headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      },body: "success"};
    }
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: {status: "fail", message: "Test"}
    };
  }

},
options: {
  action: function () {
      return {statusCode:200,headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Method': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, X-User-Id, X-Auth-Token'
      }};
    }
  }
  });
```

I have added the options and post method to allow the preflight and the actual post then but I always get unauthorized as response although I include the login credentials like in the docs of restivus specified (and they do work in Postman).
So where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is more than obvious after finding out.
I just need to to set the options method in the restivus route to authRequired: false.
You cannot send a complete header with credentials when doing a preflight.
Now I am first doing the preflight and then sending the real post.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure this out. In the next update to Restivus, v0.8.0, I've made it so that the OPTIONS endpoints are no longer affected by the auth and role requirements on a route. Those options now have to be explicitly configured on the OPTIONS endpoint, to avoid this unexpected behavior. v0.8.0 should be out in about two weeks, if all goes according to plan (when does it ever?). https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/commit/a1630865c861a1448c7bdb6c71fca0b889d04209#diff-5d6d4c4facf5b6f28ea5dc0f8a86ce9eR101

Answer (score 0):

I have set my Restivus config to be like so,

```
let Api = new Restivus({
    useDefaultAuth: false,
    prettyJson: true,
    version: 'v1',
    enableCors: false, // or set true in production
    defaultOptionsEndpoint: {
        action: function() {
            this.response.writeHead(201, {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Z-Key, X-Auth-Token, X-User-Id',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
            });
            this.done();
            return { status: true }
        }
    },
});
```

Make sure you are using the package version > 0.8 inorder to use the defaultOptionsEndpoint method, as kahmali commented. There is no need to use WebApp.connectHandlers anywhere.